# What is Android kapt and its usage? What's the difference between annotation processor and kapt in Gradle when adding dependencies?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm a bit confused on the newest annotation processor introduce in Android and related to Kotlin which is 
"kapt"
Question :

1. What is kapt ( kotlin annotation processing tool) and its uses case?
   Or what does apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' help us within
   our android project.
2. Difference between Kapt and annotationProcessor in Gradle

   Example:-

   //Dagger with annotationProcessor vs with kapt

   annotationProcessor libraries.daggerCompiler

   kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"

Comment: Actually it not relate to implementation or compile, it just support handle annotations in kotlin, you should search about compare between annotationProcessor and kapt

Comment: @CôngHải : Sure, will do . Follow up questoin,  when I defiend kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion" was I telling the compiler that the room components Ive used which carries annotation like @ module @ Entity etc  are annoted with kapt?

Comment: 1.  Kapt is the Kotlin Annotation Processing Tool, and it’s in pretty good shape these days. If you want to be able to reference generated code from Kotlin, you need to use kapt. To do that, simply include the plugin in your build.gradle file with the line 
: apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' 

2. where you would normally use the annotationProcessor keyword to specify your processor dependency, instead use the kapt keyword

Comment: @vijaychhalotre not in a good shape anymore: "kapt is in maintenance mode. We are keeping it up-to-date with recent Kotlin and Java releases but have no plans to implement new features." from its website

Answer (score 20):

"Kapt is the Kotlin Annotation Processing Tool" you need this, to generate annotated code in compile time
you can see more info in [this](https://medium.com/@daptronic/annotation-processing-with-kapt-and-gradle-237793f2be57) article

Comment: 1. Kapt is the Kotlin Annotation Processing Tool, and it’s in pretty good shape these days. If you want to be able to reference generated code from Kotlin, you need to use kapt. To do that, simply include the plugin in your build.gradle file with the line :